# Remove a listener when the listener executes

Tags: javafx-8

I have a special case where I want to add a listener to a visible property, and then have the listener removed when the property is no longer visible.  I only want the listener to fire one time and then be removed.

ie

```
ChangeListener<Boolean> listener= (obs, ov, nv) -> {
    if(!nv){
        //do my processing
        node.visibleProperty().removeListener(listener);                    }
        }
    };
node.visibleProperty().addListener(listener);
```

However it tells me that the variable listener may not have been initialized.  If I try by making it null, then creating it, it complains that it is not effectively final

Is this possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can either make `listener` an instance variable, instead of a local variable, or you can use an anonymous inner class (in which you can use the keyword `this` to refer to itself):

```
ChangeListener<Boolean> listener = new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> obs, Boolean ov, Boolean nv)  {
        if (! nv) {
            node.visibleProperty().removeListener(this);
        }
    }
};
node.visibleProperty().addListener(listener);
```

Comment: Thank you - I didn't even think to use an inner class instead of a lambda.

Comment: @purringpigeon Ah, the youth of today. When I was a lad, we didn't even have lambda expressions, etc etc.

Comment: Youth?  I've been doing this for 20 + years.  I just went so far into lambda I didn't think of coming back.  haha.